# c# SQL data type and query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

The method of my code is as below:

```
protected void AddBtn_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string text1 = TextBox1.Text;
    string text2 = TextBox2.Text;
    string text3 = TextBox3.Text;
    string text4 = TextBox4.Text;
    string text5 = TextBox5.Text;
    string text6 = TextBox6.Text;
    string text7 = TextBox7.Text;
    string text8 = TextBox8.Text;
    string text9 = TextBox9.Text;


    if (pnAvailiable == 1)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XMLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string str = "INSERT INTO XML (Part_Number, PowerMin_dBm_RoomTemp, PowerMax_dBm_RoomTemp, ERMin_dB_RoomTemp, ERMax_dB_RoomTemp, OMAMin_uW_RoomTemp, OMAMax_uW_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMin_W_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMax_W_RoomTemp) VALUES (" + text1 + "," + text2 + "," + text3 + "," + text4 + "," + text5 + "," + text6 + "," + text7 + "," + text8 + "," + text9 + ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

My database's data type is define as text

The problem is:

1. when the Textbox1 input is an integer, it supposed to convert to string and text1 is a string. But when inserting to the sql, it report error as "int is incompatible with text" and report at "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"
2. I change to varchar(50) for my data type in database. The new problem is when I input "6-1", it operates first and put "5" into the database. When I input "a-3", it will report error.

Actually, I just want to type in string and put string into the database.

Please help me figure out the problem. Please indicate which problem you are

Comment: Firstly, read up on SQL parameters

Comment: I see. you guys help me a lot. My silly question. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void AddBtn_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string text1 = TextBox1.Text;
    string text2 = TextBox2.Text;
    string text3 = TextBox3.Text;
    string text4 = TextBox4.Text;
    string text5 = TextBox5.Text;
    string text6 = TextBox6.Text;
    string text7 = TextBox7.Text;
    string text8 = TextBox8.Text;
    string text9 = TextBox9.Text;


    if (pnAvailiable == 1)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XMLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string str = "INSERT INTO XML (Part_Number, PowerMin_dBm_RoomTemp, PowerMax_dBm_RoomTemp, ERMin_dB_RoomTemp, ERMax_dB_RoomTemp, OMAMin_uW_RoomTemp, OMAMax_uW_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMin_W_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMax_W_RoomTemp) VALUES (@text1,@text2,@text3,@text4,@text5,@text6,@text7,@text8,@text9)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text1", text1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text2", text2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text3", text3);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text4", text4);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text5", text5);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text6", text6);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text7", text7);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text8", text8);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text9", text9);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to read this blog post: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I agree that explicitly setting the types for the parameters is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **Sql Parameter** instead of just join a string.
Like

```
   SqlCommand timeSlotCmd = new SqlCommand("delete from xxxxxx   where LeagueId=@LeagueId", conn, tran);
   command.Parameters.Add("@LeagueId", leagueIdValue);
   timeSlotCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: +1. Although not directly answering the question, this is of unquestionable importance when using an SQL API.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not surrounding the values in single quotes, it is subtracting 1 from 6 when it encounters `6-1`.  This unexpected behavior is a symptom of a serious security vulnerability that you have in your code.  You should spend some time getting familiar with [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) vulnerabilities (currently #1 on the OWASP top 10 list).

Luckily for you, the correct solution will take care of both the error you have encountered as well as the SQL Injection vulnerability.

To fix both problems look into using [parameterized queries](http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx?SQL%20Injection%20And%20Parameterized%20Queries).  Using a parameterized query you can specify the data type of each parameter (while also preventing malicious code injection).  For example:

```
INSERT INTO XML (Part_Number, ......) VALUES (" + text1 + " ...
```

Would become

```
INSERT INTO XML (Part_Number, ......) VALUES (@PartNumber ...
```

This is also much easier to read IMHO.  You will need to add the parameter(s) to the SqlCommand object:

```
SqlParameter PartNumber = new SqlParameter("@PartNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
PartNumber.Value = "whatever...";
cmd.Parameters.Add(PartNumber);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to add parameters.

```
 string str = "INSERT INTO XML (Part_Number, ...) VALUES (:text1, ...)";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
 cmd.AddParam(":text1", DbType.Int, 1, ParameterDirection.Input);
 .....
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
 Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
string str = "INSERT INTO XML (Part_Number, PowerMin_dBm_RoomTemp, PowerMax_dBm_RoomTemp, ERMin_dB_RoomTemp, ERMax_dB_RoomTemp, OMAMin_uW_RoomTemp, OMAMax_uW_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMin_W_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMax_W_RoomTemp) VALUES (" + text1 + "," + text2 + "," + text3 + "," + text4 + "," + text5 + "," + text6 + "," + text7 + "," + text8 + "," + text9 + ")";
```

into following

```
"INSERT INTO XML (Part_Number, PowerMin_dBm_RoomTemp, PowerMax_dBm_RoomTemp, ERMin_dB_RoomTemp, ERMax_dB_RoomTemp, OMAMin_uW_RoomTemp, OMAMax_uW_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMin_W_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMax_W_RoomTemp) VALUES ('" + text1 + "','" + text2 + "','" + text3 + "','" + text4 + "','" + text5 + "','" + text6 + "','" + text7 + "','" + text8 + "','" + text9 + "')";
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query is incorrect the varchar should be inserted in single codes ('Value of your Row')
Try this

```
string str = "INSERT INTO XML (Part_Number, PowerMin_dBm_RoomTemp, PowerMax_dBm_RoomTemp, ERMin_dB_RoomTemp, ERMax_dB_RoomTemp, OMAMin_uW_RoomTemp, OMAMax_uW_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMin_W_RoomTemp, ModPowerConsumptionMax_W_RoomTemp) VALUES ('" + text1 + "','" + text2 + "','" + text3 + "','" + text4 + "','" + text5 + "','" + text6 + "','" + text7 + "','" + text8 + "','" + text9 + "')";
```

Comment: SQL Injection vulnerability

Comment: I don't how to mark more than on answer as the answer. you both make the right one

Comment: what security problem? could you please give more detail or point it out.

Comment: It's valid to note "SQL Injection vulnerability" for the coding technique; it needs to be pointed out. It's less clear if it's a meaningful possibility for this case without knowing the intended users and other details. E.g., the code might run on the OP's PC against a single table DB and be a simple data entry convenience for only the OP; or it could be public-facing and open huge holes into an enterprise DB. The risk is real; but relevance is 'Maybe'.